# Sharepoint 2013 on Office 365 - Best practice about MasterPage

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

We are going through the process of moving our Intranet on Sharepoint 2013 on Office 365. Talking with Microsoft guys we've been told to avoid master page customisation and work with javascript/css and page layouts for branding. So my question is:

- Is this possibile in the real world?
- Is there any limitation if we accept to don't customise the master page?
- Anyone has experience in this approach and can give us feedback?

Looking on internet 90% of branding examples include master page customisation...

Thanks
Emilio

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and we have done it for one of our client. The best way I would suggest is to use custom page layouts and the default OOB O365 master page. That way if they push any changes in the OOB master page it will not affect your site and new features would be available on the site.

To quickly get rid of the OOB SharePoint components you can use the css

```
    <style>
#s4-titlerow {
    display: none!important;
}
.ms-core-navigation {
    DISPLAY: none !important;
}
#contentBox {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and yes there will be limitations. But you can do quite a bit of branding with pure CSS. A good example is [Heather Solomon's post](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/02/sptechcon-austin-february-2015/).

Answer (score 0):

The questions point back to you.. What level of customisations are you looking for?

Custom master pages are definitely required to do build all the funky branding and customisations. However, because Office 365 is a rapidly changing environment, there's always a chance that your customisations would break and its your responsibility to maintain it not Microsoft's.

You can do a basic level of branding with themes/composed looks.

The way I look at it -  Intranets, in most organisations,need to be branded. So review and if needed build a customised master page. But keep team sites (collaboration sites) as they are.

Refer to this article regarding recent guidance - [New Guidance from Microsoft for Packaging and Deploying SharePoint Solutions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobgerman/archive/2015/01/31/new-guidance-from-microsoft-for-packaging-and-deploying-sharepoint-solutions.aspx)